# UITextField selectAll and no menu after tap on another uitextfield

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

I have some UITextField that when the user tap on it, I select all the text and the menu is hidden, but if they don't make any change, when they tap on another UITextField, the menú Cut, Copy, Replace appears on the current UITextfield, not in the tapped UITextfield.

I can hide the menu the first time just after the selectAll, but not when the user taps on another UITextfield.

Any ideas ?

thanks,

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

   [textField selectAll:textField];
   [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the delegate for the other text field(s)?

Example: `myTextField.delegate = self;`

Answer (score 0):

The `textField` variable in the delegate method should be the second `UITextField` when touched. You can identify your `UITextField`s with tags. Thus:

```
#define kSecondTextFieldTag 300
// ....

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField.tag == kSecondTextFieldTag) {
        [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Yeah, and make sure you set the delegates as suggested before.

Comment: In my case I want to hide it always, so I have this code [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO; executing always, no matter wich field is begining to edit, so I don't understant what you are proposing, sorry